# How to correct UIView and UILabel text scaling with pixelation?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiview, catextlayer

When I add a `UILabel` with text to a `UIView` and then scale the `UIView`, the contents is displayed with pixelation. The greater the scale factor, the greater the pixelation.

I understand using a `CATextLayer` might be able to assist and could display the scaled `UIView` and `UILabel` text without pixelation but I don't know how to implement it.

This is how I create a triangle and scale it with no pixelation. It scales with perfect sharp edges.

***How can I ensure the same when scaling a `UILabel` ?***

```
func drawTriangle() {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
    path.closePath()

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = path.CGPath
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    viewTriangle.layer.insertSublayer(shape, atIndex: 0)
}

func scaleTriangle() {
    viewTriangle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5, 5)
}
```

---

**Question:**

***In Swift code, how do I convert the below to use a `CATextLayer` so that it scales with no pixelation?***

---

**Problem code:**

```
func drawLetter() { // pixelated when scaled ?
    let labelLetter = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    labelLetter.text = "A"
    labelLetter.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    labelLetter.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    labelLetter.font = UIFont(name: labelLetter.font.fontName, size: 144)
    labelLetter.textAlignment = .Center
    viewLetter.addSubview(labelLetter)
    }
}

func scaleView() {
    let scaleValue: CGFloat = 5
    self.viewLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleValue, scaleValue)
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: is there a reason you are using scale instead of actually changing the height/width of the view to make it bigger? you could do that to resolve the pixelation issue

Comment: HI, @Rishabh . I guess I use a transform scale method because it animates well with a `UIView.animateWithDuration` method. So I’m really looking for a transform scale method, but I’m happy to look at other suggestions. I’ve just updated the question with more details.

Comment: @user4806509 Did the below answer not work?

Comment: Thanks, @Mars Unfortunately adding `.contentScaleFactor` does not eliminate the pixellation.

Comment: Perhaps you could make your label font 5x larger and set initial scale to 0.2 and then when you want to zoom it you would scale it to 1.0 scale.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand using a CATextLayer uses paths for drawing and will display the scaled UIView and UILabel text without pixelation.

You understand wrong. A CATextLayer *draws* text and scales *its* text. This is an either-or thing: use CATextLayer *or* a UILabel.

It's easy to get more detail in a scaled view: that is what a view's [`contentScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622657-contentscalefactor) is for. Simply increase it, taking into account the existing scale due to the resolution of the screen, to match your scale transform.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not understanding @matt . Can you show in code how to use `contentScaleFactor` to scale `viewLetter` above? Also, is `contentScaleFactor` able to be animated when using a `UIView.animateWithDuration(`?

Comment: Hi, @Matt , I asked a very specific Swift question and you gave an incomplete answer with vague reference to contentScaleFactor which you wouldn’t elaborate on. You followed up with a link to a very broad topic, not an answer, in an Objective C book that links to a paid book you author and are promoting, seen across many other answers you have posted on StackOverflow, see https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apeth.com%2FiOSBook%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com. Forgive me, but this is inappropriate. Either try help with a focused answer to the question or refrain from spamming StackOverflow please.

Answer (score 1):

This scales up the view 5x and sets the content's scale as well

```
func scaleView() {
    let scaleValue: CGFloat = 5
    self.viewLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleValue, scaleValue)
    self.labelLetter.contentScaleFactor = scaleValue * x //scaleValue * native content scale  (2 on iPhone 8 and 3 on iPhone 8 plus)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mars Unfortunately adding `.contentScaleFactor` does not eliminate the pixellation.

Comment: It worked for me... but I modified the code a little bit. Try plugging in higher values for x

Comment: X is not arbitrary; its the native content scale times the zoom. In the above its 2*5 or 10 on iPhone 8 and 3*5 or 15 on iPhone 8 plus.

Comment: Thanks, edited that in. I personally tested it with an arbitrary number and had no issues with overscaling, but good to know that it can be determined

Comment: Thanks, @Mars. So you aren't getting pixellated output but instead perfectly precise letter "A" at x5 x10 x15 etc ?

Comment: @user4806509 I believe so. When I tested it, I wasn't using English characters/font, but it should still be the same. Is it still not working for you?